Group by with custom no disjoint groups in Oracle SQL
Oracle 19c
I have a table with more than 20 columns with numeric values and I want to sum them by custom groups based in one column. For example in the next table, I want the sum of Quant_1 and Quant_2 columns, based on groups G1, G2 and G3 where G1 are the rows where Category (numeric values) is <= 2, G2 are the rows where Category is <= 4 even 1 and 2, and G3 are the rows where Category is <= 6.



Name
Category
Quant_1
Quant_2




name1
1
10
5


name1
1
10
5


name2
2
11
6


name1
3
12
7


name2
4
13
8


name1
5
14
9


name2
6
15
10


name1
7
20
20



So, in this example I want to do the aggregation by Name and my custom group to get this result:



Name
Group
Quant_1
Quant_2




name1
G1
20
10


name1
G2
32
17


name1
G3
46
26


name2
G1
11
6


name2
G2
24
14


name2
G3
39
24



How do I get those column sums based on these conditions?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Thanks to the help of @MTO, I found one solution where I need to create only the number of columns as the number of custom groups. This solution has two versions depending on the version of Oracle.
The idea is to create new columns, one for each custom group using CASE, and aggregate the quantities in grouping sets of Name and each of the columns that represent the custom groups. And finally UNPIVOT them.
The difference between versions is because, as @MTO mentioned in his comment, in earlier versions is not possible to use alias columns in the HAVING clause.
So, for oracle 23c you can use: Fiddle V1
SELECT Name, grp, quant_1, quant_2
FROM (
  SELECT name,
         SUM(quant_1) AS quant_1,
         SUM(quant_2) AS quant_2,
         CASE WHEN category <= 2 THEN 'G1' END AS g1,
         CASE WHEN category <= 4 THEN 'G2' END AS g2,
         CASE WHEN category <= 6 THEN 'G3' END AS g3         
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((name, g1), (name, g2), (name, g3))
  HAVING g1 IS NOT NULL or g2 IS NOT NULL or G3 IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY name, g1, g2, g3
)
UNPIVOT (
  VALUE FOR grp IN (
    g1,g2,g3
  )
)

And for earlier versions, you need to use a subquery, with something like this: Fiddle V2
SELECT Name, grp, quant_1, quant_2
FROM (
  SELECT name,
         SUM(quant_1) AS quant_1,
         SUM(quant_2) AS quant_2,
         g1,
         g2,
         g3
  FROM   (
    SELECT name,
         quant_1,
         quant_2,
         CASE WHEN category <= 2 THEN 'G1' END AS g1,
         CASE WHEN category <= 4 THEN 'G2' END AS g2,
         CASE WHEN category <= 6 THEN 'G3' END AS g3         
    FROM   table_name
  )
  GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((name, g1), (name, g2), (name, g3))
  ORDER BY name, g1, g2, g3
)
UNPIVOT (
  VALUE FOR grp IN (
    g1,g2,g3
  )
)

So, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (Name, Category, Quant_1, Quant_2) AS
SELECT 'name1', 1, 10,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name1', 1, 10,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name2', 2, 11,  6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name1', 3, 12,  7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name2', 4, 13,  8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name1', 5, 14,  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name2', 6, 15, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name1', 7, 20, 20 FROM DUAL;

With both methods, your result is going to be:



NAME
GRP
QUANT_1
QUANT_2




name1
G1
20
10


name1
G2
32
17


name1
G3
46
26


name2
G1
11
6


name2
G2
24
14


name2
G3
39
24



Also, you can find the excellent approach of @MTO here Fiddle MTO.

Use conditional aggregation to aggregate into columns and then UNPIVOT columns to rows:
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         SUM(CASE WHEN category <= 2 THEN quant_1 END) AS g1_q1,
         SUM(CASE WHEN category <= 2 THEN quant_2 END) AS g1_q2,
         SUM(CASE WHEN category <= 4 THEN quant_1 END) AS g2_q1,
         SUM(CASE WHEN category <= 4 THEN quant_2 END) AS g2_q2,
         SUM(CASE WHEN category <= 6 THEN quant_1 END) AS g3_q1,
         SUM(CASE WHEN category <= 6 THEN quant_2 END) AS g3_q2
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY name
)
UNPIVOT (
  (quant_1, quant_2) FOR grp IN (
    (g1_q1, g1_q2) AS 'G1',
    (g2_q1, g2_q2) AS 'G2',
    (g3_q1, g3_q2) AS 'G3'
  )
)

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (Name, Category, Quant_1, Quant_2) AS
SELECT 'name1', 1, 10,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name1', 1, 10,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name2', 2, 11,  6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name1', 3, 12,  7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name2', 4, 13,  8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name1', 5, 14,  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name2', 6, 15, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name1', 7, 20, 20 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



NAME
GRP
QUANT_1
QUANT_2




name1
G1
20
10


name1
G2
32
17


name1
G3
46
26


name2
G1
11
6


name2
G2
24
14


name2
G3
39
24



fiddle

Thank you so much for your help @MTO. I have 40 columns with data that I want to aggregate, so using your approach I will have to create 120 columns and then unpivote them. But based on your approach I created an alternative solution where I only have to create three columns (because I have three custom groups), then I do a GROUP BY with GROUPING SETS, and finally I Unpivote them. Find this approach here: Link. I will appreciate your feedback if you have any. Thank you again.

@YeltsinParmenioVegaNiño In earlier Oracle versions you cannot use the column alias in the HAVING clause and would need something like fiddle. You should post your solution as an answer (self-answers are acceptable and encouraged).
